# I need to count the number of dates selected in a multidatepicker and pass that count to a pdf report ?how to do that

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, bootstrap-datepicker

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var date_input=$('input[name="rosterdate"]'); //our date input has the name "myrosterdate"
  var container=$('.bootstrap-iso form').length>0 ? $('.bootstrap-iso form').parent() : "body";
  var options={
  multidate:true,
  format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
    container: container,
    todayHighlight: true,
    autoclose: false,
  };
  date_input.datepicker(options);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [Bootstrap Datepicker Events documentation](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/events.html), you can hook to the `changeDate` event of the control. From there you can interrogate the `dates` property of the event to get an array of the selected dates, using `length` to determine how many selections have been made.

Alternatively you can use the [`getDates` metod](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/methods.html#getdates) to retrieve the dates under any other event, outside of the control.

```js
jQuery($ => {
  let $date_input = $('input[name="rosterdate"]'); //our date input has the name "myrosterdate"
  let $container = $('.bootstrap-iso form').length > 0 ? $('.bootstrap-iso form').parent() : "body";
  
  $date_input.datepicker({
    multidate: true,
    format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
    container: $container,
    todayHighlight: true,
    autoclose: false,
  }).on('changeDate', e => {
    // get count of dates when a selection is made
    console.log(e.dates.length);
  });
  
  $('form').on('submit', e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    
    // get count of dates when submitting your form
    let dates = $date_input.datepicker('getDates');
    console.log(dates.length);
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.9.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js" integrity="sha512-T/tUfKSV1bihCnd+MxKD0Hm1uBBroVYBOYSk1knyvQ9VyZJpc/ALb4P0r6ubwVPSGB2GvjeoMAJJImBG12TiaQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.9.0/css/bootstrap-datepicker.min.css" integrity="sha512-mSYUmp1HYZDFaVKK//63EcZq4iFWFjxSL+Z3T/aCt4IO9Cejm03q3NKKYN6pFQzY0SBOr8h+eCIAZHPXcpZaNw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />


<div class="bootstrap-iso">
  <form>
    <input type="text" name="rosterdate" />
    <button>Submit</button>
  </form>
</div>
```